# Is it safe to remove a Python reference to a Qt object directly after calling deleteLater()?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Please consider the minimal example below, which implements a custom `QNetworkAccessManager` that maintains a list of unfinished `QNetworkReply` instances.

When a reply is `finished`, it is removed from the `unfinished_replies` list.

As discussed in [Is deleteLater() necessary in PyQt/PySide?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20164015), `QNetworkReply.deleteLater()` is used, inside the `finished` slot, to schedule the Qt object for deletion.

However, I am not sure what would be the best way to remove the Python reference to the reply object. I can think of two (mutually exclusive) options for removing the Python reference, as shown in the example below:

1. remove directly after calling `deleteLater()`
2. remove when the `QNetworkReply.destroyed` signal is emitted ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed))

Both options seem to work just fine. I would prefer option 1, but I'm not sure if this could lead to surprises in rare cases. Which would be best? Or is there another alternative?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork, QtWidgets, QtCore


class CustomNetworkAccessManager(QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomNetworkAccessManager, self).__init__()
        self.unfinished_replies = []
        self.finished.connect(self.slot)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        reply = super(CustomNetworkAccessManager, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        reply.index = i  # just for printing
        self.unfinished_replies.append(reply)

    def remove_from_list(self, reply):
        self.unfinished_replies.remove(reply)
        print('{} unfinished replies left'.format(len(self.unfinished_replies)))
        if not self.unfinished_replies:
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    def slot(self, reply):
        print('reply {} finished'.format(reply.index))
        # handle the Qt side:
        reply.deleteLater()  
        # handle the Python side:
        # either
        # OPTION 1 - remove now
        self.remove_from_list(reply)
        # or 
        # OPTION 2 - remove when destroyed
        # reply.destroyed.connect(lambda: self.remove_from_list(reply))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = CustomNetworkAccessManager()

    # Schedule requests
    url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    for i in range(6):
        manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl(url)))

    # Start event loop
    app.exec_()
```

p.s. sorry for the Python 2 code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are equivalent, they only differ the moment they are removed. But to understand more in detail you have to understand how the PyQt5/PySide2 binding works. Those libraries create a wrapper around the C++ object, something like:

```py
class FooWrapper:
    def __new__(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
         # ...
         instance = ...
         instance._cpp_object = create_cpp_object()
         # ...
         return instance

    def foo_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return execute_foo_method(self._cpp_object, *args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self):
        destroyed_cpp_object(self._cpp_object)
```

So when calling deleteLater only the cpp_object is deleted and not the wrapper, you can verify that if you use:

```py
reply.destroyed.connect(self.remove_from_list)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    reply.destroyed.connect(self.remove_from_list)
  File "main.py", line 17, in remove_from_list
    self.unfinished_replies.remove(reply)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

since the parameter passed by destroyed is an invalid wrapper getting the above error. For this case, a solution is to check if the cpp_object has been removed with sip.isdeleted():

```py
from PyQt5 import QtNetwork, QtWidgets, QtCore
import sip

# ...
class CustomNetworkAccessManager(QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager):
    # ...

    def remove_from_list(self):
        self.unfinished_replies = [
            reply for reply in self.unfinished_replies if not sip.isdeleted(reply)
        ]
        print("{} unfinished replies left".format(len(self.unfinished_replies)))
        if not self.unfinished_replies:
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()

    def slot(self, reply):
        print("reply {} finished".format(reply.index))
        # handle the Qt side:
        reply.deleteLater()
        # handle the Python side:
        reply.destroyed.connect(self.remove_from_list)
```

Returning to the study of your methods, these can be graphed as follows:

```
(FIRST METHOD)
------------┬------------------┬---------------------┬-----------------------
            |                  |                     |
 call_deleteLater remove_reply_from_list          destroyed
```

```
(SECOND METHOD)
------------┬-----------------------------------------┬-----------------┬------
            |                                         |                 |
 call_deleteLater                               destroyed remove_reply_from_list
```

And since you are using the original wrappers you should not have any problem.

**Conclusion:** Both are equivalent and safe.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer. The `lambda` in option 2 in my example was actually a leftover from a more complicated piece of code, but actually `reply.destroyed.connect(self.remove_from_list)`, without the `lambda` also seems to work on my system: I am not seeing the `ValueError`. Am I missing the point here? (this is based on legacy code using Python 2.7 and PyQt 5.6)

Comment: @djvg There may be a difference between the APIs or maybe it is caused by the python version, I have tested it with PyQt5 5.14.2 and python 3.8.2. Your method with the lambda is safer compared to the one I used in my explanation